# MDX query: filter and sum of filtered

Tags: sql, filter, mdx

I've just started to learn MDX and i want to do a query like that: 
filter data by the cost ( i've already made that query but without the sum) like that:

`SELECT [Measures].[SumOfSelled] ON 0,`

`FILTER ([From].[From].[City].members, [Measures].[SumOfSelled]>7000) ON 1`

`FROM [BI-Avia]`

It's working

and it is OK
BUT!!! 
I need also to show the sum of filtered elements under this filtered result by cities

I know how to find it separately:

`with member [Measures].FilteredSum as` `sum(filter([From].From].City].members,Measures].SunOfSelled]>7000),Measures].[SumOfSelled])`
`select{SumOfSelled} on 0`
`from [BI-AVIA]`

But i have to show this together!! The SUM under Filtered! two in one! I need youe help! I think it's very clear for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just define the calculated member on the `[From].[From]` hierarchy and then combine both queries, using a union of sets (abbreviated with `+` in MDX):

```
with member [From].[From].FilteredSum as 
     sum(filter([From].[From].City].members, Measures].SumOfSelled]>7000))

SELECT [Measures].[SumOfSelled]
       ON 0,

       FILTER ([From].[From].[City].members, [Measures].[SumOfSelled]>7000)
       +
       { [From].[From].FilteredSum }
       ON 1

FROM [BI-Avia]
```

You could possibly define the filter as a set in the WITH clause, which would avoid that Analysis Services evaluates it twice.